# How to find the name of a table if a unique row in it is known

Tags: mysql

if i have a unique entry (row) for each of my tables could someone tell me the mysql query to fetch the name of the table in which this unique row is present out of a list of tables of my database?

Comment: You can use the `information_schema` database for that maybe. But it does not make much sense in a relational schema. You should know what data it is and in what table it belongs.

Comment: I can't envisage any scenario where this would be useful. Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @anna - surely you don't have so many tables with the same structure that you cannot simply check each one?  If you know the row in question, you can certainly narrow down the search to tables that contain that row structure, which should be at most only a very few tables, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, but you would need to know a column name:

```
DECLARE @TBL VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @QRY AS VARCHAR(5000)
CREATE TABLE #TBLS(
    TBLNAME VARCHAR(100)
    )

SELECT * 
INTO #TBLNMS 
FROM (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    ) AS TB;

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM #TBLNMS)
BEGIN
    SET @TBL = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM #TBLNMS)   
    SET @QRY = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM [' + @TBL + '] 
            WHERE INPUT = 134513) 
            INSERT INTO #TBLS VALUES(''' + @TBL + ''');';
    EXEC (@QRY);

    DELETE FROM #TBLNMS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TBL;
END
SELECT * FROM #TBLS;
DROP TABLE #TBLS;
DROP TABLE #TBLNMS;
```